# A library with variable in config.h file

Tags: arrays, c, parameter-passing, header-files

I'm writing a library in which the user has to declare his own variables in `config.h` file.

This library has three files: the main file which is `lib.c`, the `.h` file, `lib.h` and the config file: `config.h`. As all libraries, user must only change the `config.h` file. He has to declare an array of numbers he needs. The problem is that we can't initialize the array in `.h` files.

A solution I was thinking of, is that the user passes his array and `sizeof` his array to all of my `lib.c` functions as arguments, but I want to know what is the standard? What do professional programmers do in other libraries? (**edit**: The `lib.c` includes the `lib.h` and `lib.c` includes the `config.h` file.)

Note: the array that the user needs, is constant. He has to define it just once and pass it to all the functions. This is why I wanted to initialize the array in the `config.h` file (So that it is declared just once). (No need to mention that the `sizeof` array is constant too.)

The `config.h` file:

```
#define BTN0    {BTN0_GPIO_Port, BTN0_Pin} //user defines these
#define BTN1    {BTN1_GPIO_Port, BTN1_Pin}

typedef struct {
    GPIO_TypeDef* port;
    uint16_t pin;
} btn;

const btn btns[] = {BTN0, BTN1};

#define BUTTON_ARR_SIZE     sizeof(btns)/sizeof(btns[0])
#define BUTTON_NOT_FOUND    BUTTON_ARR_SIZE //returns btn[n] which is not available. I use this line of definition in my library, and user needs it in his code.
```

in `lib.c` file:

```
bool checkPressAndReleaseUsingMask(btn button){ //private function. User doesn't call it.
    if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(button.port, button.pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET) {
        while (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(button.port, button.pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
            osDelay(20);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

uint32_t find1Btn(){
    uint32_t whichBtn = BUTTON_NOT_FOUND;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < BUTTON_ARR_SIZE; i++){
        if(checkPressAndReleaseUsingMask(btns[i])){
            whichBtn = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return whichBtn;
}
//bla bla bla
```

the `lib.h`:

```
#include "config.h"
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t find1Btn(void);
```

User code:

```
        int x = find1Btn();
        if(x != BUTTON_NOT_FOUND){ //No button is pressed
            //do sth.
        }
```

Comment: `#define MYLIB_ARRAY 1,2,3,4`, then in `lib.c` do `static int arr[] = {MYLIB_ARRAY};`?

Comment: You can declare a `const int array[] = { 7, 17, 38};` in a header file. Just don't forget the word `const`.

Comment: `The problem is that we can't initialize the array in .h files.`
why not?

Comment: To me it sounds like you're overcomplicating stuff. Remember that you can hide the complexity from the programmer who is using the library. Having to edit a `config.h` has a bad smell for me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's not an int[]. I've added some code. Please read that again.

Comment: @klutt As I know (maybe my knowledge isn't enough), all libraries have a `.c` file, one `.h` file for headers and etc, and another `config.h` file which user can config how to use the library. For example, imagine that we have a library for flash memory management. The user who is using this, has to declare HIS OWN FLASH MEMORY information in `config.h` file. Some stuff like the `sector size` and `total sectors` of his own memory.

Comment: @Raildex @mch We can't initialize in .h files. Related error: `Symbol x (btns here) multiply defined in xxx.o and zzz.o`. More info stackoverflow.com/a/8109149/9691976

Comment: @MohammadKholghi Yes, there are cases where it's suitable. But compare to the `rand()` function, which you initialize with `srand(time(0))`. I assume you would not want to have to construct a separate `config.h` for that?

Comment: Is the programmer meant to ever access `btns` directly?

Comment: @klutt `rand()` takes the `time(0)` as argument, and it's just once. Then he just reads the random number. In my library, every-time the user wants a function, either he has to pass the whole array and size to them, either declaring the array in `config.h` file. I can't declare it in `config.h` file. Do you know what we can do in c?

Comment: @klutt No. He just declares it. It's used in the `lib.c` functions.

Comment: How much stuff is it in the config file? Does it really motivate having it all in a separate file?

Comment: @klutt It's not about a new file. It's about the library standards. A library needs to have a `.c`, `.h`, and a `conf.h` file. When a user wants to use the library, he just changes some simple stuff in the config file. He MUST NOT touch the `.c` file. Whenever a library is standard, the user must be able to use it without reading the code. I surely can remove the whole `config` file, but whenever the next user wants to use my library, he has to read and change the `.c` file.

Comment: We already see that this question leads to opinion-based comments (and possibly answers), so it might be closed soon. -- Anyway, don't use a "config.h", I don't think it's professional. I never found this method in professional software. Use an initialization function and give it the user-provided structure. Store the structure or its reference and use it in the other functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I want to know what is the standard?

There is no standard.

`config.h` is typically generated in [autotools-ish projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Autotools).

> What do professional programmers do in other libraries?

Every possible way.
There are IDEs that mange configuration.
There are [build systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) and most probably each and every solution has its own different interface to manage project configuration Linux kernel has built it's whole big [kconfig](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/index.html). CMake has command line options, but also even cmake-gui. Mentioned GNU autotools has `./configure --enable-this --disable-that` and it generates `config.h` file. Many simple libraries just have a user customizable header, just like you proposed.

Note that using a central single header file will make it (almost) impossible to use the same library multiple times with different configuration within the same project. If going with a static header name, I would only recommend choosing a different name then such a common `config.h`. I like to use decentralized location, like `library-user-config.h` or something like that - that configuration header is specific to that library and other libraries do not need it. Or maybe use a centralized location - it's all project specific.

Because of `GPIO_TypeDef`, you are most probably programming on some stm32. You may want to interest how other embedded software deals with project configuration. Browse github for [many CMake](https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L58) and other libraries and build systems. Research MBed with its big `mbed_config.h` file. See [Zephyr](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/index.html) that I like and discover Kconfig with CMake and `west`.

> He has to define it just once

In your header file you did `const btn btns[]` which means it will be defined in each and every file that `#include <config.h>`. To define it once, do `extern const btn btns[2];` and do `const btn btns[] = ....` in like `config.c`. To keep the definition in a header, allow multiple definitions - add `static` like `static const btn btns[] = ...`.

The `btn` structure definitions seems pretty not-user-changable. I believe structure definition belongs to `lib.h`, as I doubt it the user will change it. To avoid name clashes, use a "namespace"/prefix symbols with common string - like `btn_find1` or `BTN_BUTTON_ARR_SIZE`. And the macro `BUTTON_NOT_FOUND` seems pretty pointless to me and not part of user configuration - it is a constant, it could be just `UINT32_MAX` or `-1`. `uint8_t i = 0;` - I would say prefer `size_t` to express size and index in an array. And `int x = find1Btn();` - note that `find1Btn` returns an `uint32_t` not `int`, the conversion may change value. Also, the array `btns` could be sorted (possible you could use some code generator tool, like mentioned build systems (like CMake), or Python (Jinja2) or m4 or other) and use `bsearch` to speed the code.

Comment: *"To allow multiple definitions, add `static btn btns`"* - Shouldn't it be `static btn btns[]`? Maybe you intended that the brackets are included in elipsis, but I suggest changing to  `static btn btns[] = ...` to make it clear